# Laravel JWT Token Always Blacklisted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I am using the tymondesigns/jwt-auth package for my app. I use customClaims to make my token.
Here is the code for login :

```
$token_data = [
        'iss' => new Issuer('AreteHCM'),
        'iat' => new IssuedAt(Carbon::now()) ,
        'exp' => new Expiration(Carbon::now()->addDays(1)),
        'nbf' => new NotBefore(Carbon::now()),
        'sub' => new Subject('AreteHCMS'),
        'jti' => new JwtId('AreteHCM'),
        'user_data' => $user->user,
        'menu_access' => $menu_access,
        'login_time' => Carbon::now(),
];
    
$customClaims = JWTFactory::customClaims($token_data);
$payload = JWTFactory::make($customClaims);
$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload)->get();
```

For Logout, I invalidate the token, so the token can not be used anymore after the user logout.

```
JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken());
```

I'm creating API (Backend) and the front end team using Angular. Eveythings went smooth, until the user logout and try to login again. After login, the user get the new account, but when he/she wants to access my middleware always rejects the token, it says that the token is blacklisted.

Here is my middleware :

```
$token = JWTAuth::getToken();
$data = JWTAuth::getPayload($token)->toArray();
```

It always shows error :

```
The token has been blacklisted in file C:\xampp\htdocs\aretehcm\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\Manager.php on line 109
```

What I want to approach is :

- User login get new token to access the API (every API request requires header auth Bearer token)
- User logout will invalidate the token, so the token can not be used anymore to access the API
- User login will get a new token so he/she can access the API

Is there any misconception from me about the JWT-API architecture ?
Thank you in advance for your replies and answers.

Comment: How do you save token to db? Please add that code.

Comment: Try using [logout](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/auth-guard/#logout) instead of `invalidate()`

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search pointed me towards this solution:
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/983#issuecomment-275884324

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I've tried the solution by making the JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED=false
But it makes me can not invalidate the token when logging out. If the token is not invalidated, it still can be used to access the API.

Comment: Did you try setting the JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED=false
and then JWT_BLACKLIST_GRACE_PERIOD? One of them has said that setting the JWT_BLACKLIST_GRACE_PERIOD to 30 would solve the issue.

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/983#issuecomment-327079639